# Using CSS, how do I centre text at a certain point on the page?

Tags: html, css

I have a page of fixed width. I don't want to change the width. I want to centre some text on the page so that it is at the centre of the entire page.

Say, if the page width is 4000px and the screen width is 1920px, using `text-align: center;` puts the text at the centre of the visible part, that is, centred at 960. I can force it using the page width, but I want to make it so that the text is at the centre of the full width, even when I change the width.

So, if the width is 6000px, I want the text centred at 3000px. If it is 1000px, I want the text centred at 500px. And all the while, the screen size remains the same.

In addition, how do I accomplish this for a container that contains text that should be justified, but the container itself should be centred.

A reproducible example as requested:

```
#mainhead {
    background-color: pink;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 1000;
    color: #e0f2f1;
    text-align: center;
}
```

The page width in this example is set to 4000px due to other stuff. But the heading is always centred at 960px from left, rather than 2000px from the left.

Comment: you can use flexbox

Comment: Wrap the text in a container that is `100vw`, so it will always be the width of the viewport and not the page width. Then just do `display: grid; place-items: center` on the container, that should be sufficient to center your text.

Comment: @Terry, you've got it the other way around. I want the text to be centred according to the page width, REGARDLESS of the viewport.

Comment: @user17026360 use JS

Comment: @Mehran so this is completely impossible using CSS?

Comment: Then you don't need to wrapping container at all? Just use the standard tricks for horizontally centering will be fine. Please include a [mcve] in your post.

Comment: @user17026360 i think you can't retrieve screen (not viewport )size using css , but it's possible with js

Comment: I have included the part that I want specifically centred. I do need container, because I want to manipulate other properties like font and colours.

Comment: @user17026360 your question is ambiguous , if you want it to be centered horizontally place it in a {width:100vw, text-align:center} container (without body margin)

Comment: What part of the question is ambiguous?

Comment: viewport or screen ?

Comment: @Mehran and 100vw gets the viewport width, which is PRECISELY not what I want.

Comment: don't apply this css to this element , apply it to its parent.

Comment: @Mehran, NEITHER. The page is larger than the screen. My screen is 1920x1080. The page is 4000px wide. I want my text to be centred and fixed at 2000px. In the centre of the entire page, not the centre of the viewport or the screen (which sound like the same thing anyway).

Comment: you should share your full code in a snippet to make it easier for others to know what exactly you want. there are more than one way to center text or element in the container or in the viewport. your 4000px width, doesn't make sense. so please share the working code in a snippet

Answer (score 1):

Create a parent div with width 100% and make that a flexbox. Then use justify-content: center; and align-items: center; It should not matter how wide your screen is. This will make sure the text is always centered.

You should use class instead of id in most cases when doing CSS.

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.mainhead {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: red;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class = "parent"> 
  <p class="mainhead"> TEXT IS ALWAYS CENTERED </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

no matter what the screen size is.it will always be centered.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
h1,div{
outline:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>I Am Always Centered</h1>
</div>
```